# Minimal amount of removed vertices from a graph

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs

There is a set $V=\{1,2,...,n\}$-it may be considered as a vertices of a graph we build.

We pick at random independently a pairs of different elements from $V$. This makes a set of edges $\mathcal{E}$

For each pair $\{i,j\}$ probability that we pick it is equal to $p$

This makes a graph $G=(V,\mathcal{E})$

Now, let's consider a function $f$ that works in following way $f(G)=a$, where $a$ is a minimal amount of vertices that we have to remove in order to get a new graph without any $k$-cliques

> Calculate $E[f(G)]$

Regards

Comment: In what context did you encounter this question? What do you think would be a good approach for this problem?